# Default value isn't showing in ng-init -ng-submit form field - Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create an update email form with Angular1 but having troubling updating it.

So on the form, the current email is showing up which is great but when I hit the update button, w/out making any changes to the email, i get an undefined error.  I don't get the error unless I edit the email.

How can I avoid having the undefined error w/out editing the email?

on load[image: on load image]

after hitting the error[image]

here is the html code

```
<div class="row" style="margin: 0;">
          <form ng-submit="updateEmail(updateEmailForm)" role="form"
          ng-init="updateEmailForm = {email: userEmail}">
            <div class="col-sm-6 account-input-container" style="padding: 0;">
              <div class="auth-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>email address</label>
                  <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="updateEmailForm.email"
                  required="required" class="form-control" ng-value="userEmail">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div>
                <button type="submit" class="bubble-btn submit-btn pull-left" style="float: none !important;">update</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div> <!-- end row -->
```

`ng-model="updateEmailForm.email"` should load the default value from `ng-init` w/out setting `ng-value` (which is why the email is showing up), but it's not, that's where the undefined comes from.

here is angular controller

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('accountSettingCtrl', [
'$rootScope',
'$scope',
'$location',
'$state',
'$window',
'Auth',
function($rootScope, $scope, $location, $state, $window, Auth){

  //set activeSetting to 1 to display account setting view on page load
  $scope.activeSetting = 1;

  Auth.getUser().then(function(userData) {
    $scope.currentUser = userData.data;
    $scope.userEmail = $scope.currentUser.email;
  })

 // update account email
 $scope.updateEmail = function() {
   Auth.updateEmail($scope.updateEmailForm)
   .then(function(resp) {
     var messageHandler = resp.data.message;;
     var status         = resp.status
     var elementID = 'updateEmailMsg';
     createMsgDiv(messageHandler, elementID, status);
   })
   .catch(function(resp) {
     var messageHandler = resp.data.message;
     var status         = resp.status
     var elementID      = 'updateEmailMsg';
     createMsgDiv(messageHandler, elementID, status);
     $location.path('/account')
   });
 };

 // Alert Message
 var createMsgDiv = function(messageHandler, elementID, status){
   var div = document.createElement('div');
   if (status == 200) {
    div.setAttribute('class', 'alert alert-success');
   }else{
    div.setAttribute('class', 'alert alert-danger');
   }

 var a = document.createElement('a');
 a.setAttribute('class', 'close');
 a.setAttribute('data-dismiss', 'alert');
 a.setAttribute('aria-label', 'close');

 var exitBtn = document.createTextNode("X")
 a.appendChild(exitBtn);

 var strong = document.createElement('strong');
 var strongText = document.createTextNode(messageHandler);
 strong.appendChild(strongText);

 div.appendChild(a);
 div.appendChild(strong);

 var childBool = document.getElementById(elementID).hasChildNodes();

 if(childBool){
   document.getElementById(elementID).innerHTML = '';
 }
 document.getElementById(elementID).appendChild(div);
 };


 }]);
```

So `$scope.userEmail` should pass the value to `ng-init` param => `ng-init = "updateEmailForm = {email: userEmail}"`, but it's not. `ng-model="updateEmailForm.email"` is empty if `ng-value` is not present.

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong, your help will be appreciated!  I'm still a noob in Angular.

Comment: Try changing ng-int to `ng-init="updateEmailForm.email=userEmail` and remove `ng-value` from email field. Also just initialize this object in controller `$scope.updateEmailForm = {email: ""};` just in case the above stuff dint worked.

Comment: @Developer thanks for the insight, I didn't change `ng-init`, didn't work for me, but I did initlize `$scope.updateEmailForm = {email: userEmail};` in the controller and it worked.  Thanks so much!